# VBA-based macro for PPT that pastes jpeg files onto separate slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a VBA-based macro for PPT that pastes jpeg files onto separate slides (See the 【Macro 1】,below).  My question is;

> 【My Question】
>   I want to add the following function to 【Macro 1】;
>   Automatically insert the file name of the pasted image into each slide.

I tried to insert name of files using "ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Name" etc., but the macro seems to stop if such a description is inserted.

【Macro 1】
You can download [original version of this macro](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1FEBJeNEmFO_K1PSOA5C8r_oz0LDluNcg) from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1FEBJeNEmFO_K1PSOA5C8r_oz0LDluNcg).
This macro is a modified version of Ref1's macro. The linked macro can automatically paste the images to the slides without error, **but it doesn't have the ability to use the image name as the slide name**.

<s>（modified at 2020/03/29 JST）

The macro on the Box1 below is one of the prototype macros 
that were created when trying to add the desired functions to the above macro. 
I modified based on the advice in the answer, but I get a Runtime error.
I tried various places to add, but same result.</s>

（modified at 2020/03/31 JST）
Here is the completed version: This macro fulfills my requirements described in 【My Question】 successfully.
The following (ref2) was very helpful in creating this macro. You can download this [version of macro](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1FEBJeNEmFO_K1PSOA5C8r_oz0LDluNcg) from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1FEBJeNEmFO_K1PSOA5C8r_oz0LDluNcg)

[Box1]（modified at 2020/03/31 JST）

```
Sub InsertImages()
'Insert all image files from the same level folder
Dim prs As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim txt As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim tmp As PowerPoint.PpViewType
Dim fol As Object, f As Object
Dim fol_path As String
'Store open presentation in prs
Set prs = ActivePresentation

'Cancel if slide show mode
If SlideShowWindows.Count > 0 Then prs.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit

With ActiveWindow
tmp = .ViewType 'Remember window display mode
.ViewType = ppViewSlide
End With

'Get the path of the folder where this ppt file are.
fol_path = ActivePresentation.Path

  'Processing files in the folders
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not .FolderExists(fol_path) Then GoTo Fin

For Each f In .GetFolder(fol_path).Files
'Process only JPEG files
Select Case LCase(.GetExtensionName(f.Path))
Case "jpg", "jpeg"
'Add slids
Set sld = prs.Slides.Add(prs.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutChartAndText)
sld.Select
'Insert image
Set shp = sld.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName:=f.Path, _
LinkToFile:=False, _
SaveWithDocument:=True, _
Left:=0, _
Top:=0)
With shp
.LockAspectRatio = True 'Fix the aspect ratio

'Fit inserted image to slide size
            If .Width > .Height Then
              .Width = prs.PageSetup.SlideWidth
            Else
              .Height = prs.PageSetup.SlideHeight
            End If
.Select

'Resize image
.Width = .Width * 0.85
.Height = .Height * 0.85
End With

'Center image on slide
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
.Align msoAlignCenters, True
.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
End With

'Change slide title to file name
sld.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = f.Name
'Insert Text
'Set txt = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
'Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
'Left:=600, _
'Top:=50, _
'Width:=250, _
'Height:=10)

'   With txt
'   .Name = "AddedTextBox"
'   .TextFrame.TextRange = "free text"
'   .TextEffect.FontSize = 20
'   End With
End Select
Next
End With
Fin:
ActiveWindow.ViewType = tmp 'Restore window display mode
End Sub
```

【References】
(Ref.1)[指定したフォルダ内の画像ファイルを一括挿入するPowerPointマクロ](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=8228), written in Japanese.
(Ref.2)[パワーポイント　画像挿入　マクロ VBA](https://plaza.rakuten.co.jp/takupin/diary/201801260000/), written in Japanese.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't raise any errors here. Please add the statements that cause an error and indicate which lines they are.

Comment: ＠John Korchok　This macro doesn't give an error, but it doesn't have the required function "make file name slide title."　
I didn't post erred macros because it showed what seemed to be an infinite loop.

Comment: ＠John Korchok I modified the macro in [Box1].
This macro gives an error, but I believe that it will not be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a blank slide, then trying to write text to a non-existent Title placeholder. Change the layout to ppLayoutObject to get the Title and Content layout.

Then you'll also have to send the picture to the back, because it will be on top of the Title placeholder. The addition of this line will do that:

```
          With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange
            .ZOrder msoSendToBack <!--Add this to send image to back-->
            .Align msoAlignCenters, True
            .Align msoAlignMiddles, True
          End With
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried several times but it didn't work.
After deleting "<!-Add this and send image->" , executing it at the folder where the images are located, "Run-time error '-2147188160 (80048240)" appears.

Comment: It's fair to modify your question before any answers are given, but not after. I've already answered what you had originally asked and would appreciate an upvote. 

If you're getting a runtime error, clicking on the Debug button will highlight the problem line. But you have not posted which line that is in your code.

Comment: My question was successfully solved. Successful macro is shown in the Box1. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand why your answer answers my original question. Your answer did not contribute to solve my problem. But I want to pay tribute to your efforts. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Your original post had more than one question. I explained why you were getting errors and added how you were going to have to modify your code. But in the future, I'll make sure I don't answer your posts unless I can answer ALL your questions.

Comment: Unfortunately, your answer didn't fix the error either.  
Also, "<! -- "is not a valid comment for VBA. (Are you confused with Javascript?)　Ah.... But,It may be  [My Question] was in bad English. Sorry. 
If this is the good English, you've probably post the appropriate answer. Sorry for the confusion.